# Output format of the values in the given SQL server Table using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a SQL server table like this

```
CC     Descr  C_NO     Vol   Wt

2050   Des1   123      20    40
2060   Des2   123      30    50
2050   Des1   125      20    40
2060   Des2   125      30    50
2050   Des1   126      20    40
```

and I want output like this on my application

```
2050
    Des1

 123
    20
    40
 125
    20
    40   
 126
    20
    40

2060
    Des2

 123
    30
    50
 125
    30
    50
```

How can I do that using C# or C sharp code?
Let's take each value from the table as String and I am not looking for C sharp code to connect to SQL server database. Just want C# code to format my output written above.

For every similar CC value which always have similar Descr value, it shows all the C_No, Vol and Wt values related to that particular CC value in the sequence written in the output section.

Answer (score 0):

well you can achieve this using Linq in C#..I haven't tried the code but you can do something like this..

```
Var CCGroups= From c in CCList
              group c by c.cc into g
              select new {CC=g.key, OtherParam= g};

Foreach (var g in CCGroups)
  {
     Consile.writeline("{0}",g.CC);

     Foreach(var P in g.OtherParam)
       {
        Console.WriteLine{"{0},{1},{2},{3}",P.Descr,P.C_NO,P.Vol,P.Wt}
       }

 }
```

here I've assumed that data you got from database table is in List<> form..if it's not then convet it from Dataset or DataTable into List<>...

Comment: I like to see a code without using Linq? I am outputting all the data on the application side as String so we can take 2050,Des1,123 as String